# FASM using custom resource files

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, resources, fasm

How do I include my custom resource files and be able to access them with the windows api?

Comment: Looks like you found a solution http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=11577 - you should add that as an answer here for others to see

Answer (score 1):

You can find some info about resources [here](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=win32#1.8).